# Problemas com actualização da dataGrid C#

Tags: c#, sql

Tenho um código responsável por fazer abate de stocks de um determinado produto numa tabela de produtos... ele abate o stock sem problemas.. mas quando vou ao formulário de pesquisas de stocks de produtos o produto cujo o stock foi abatido não apresenta o stock actualizado... para que ele actualize necessito fechar a aplicacao e entao abrir denovo so assim ele apresenta o stock ja actualizado apos o abate, mas eu quero que ele faça o abate e quando eu consultar no formulário ele pesquisa ele mostrar o stock actualizado sem ter precisado fechar aplicação primeiro.

NB: estou usando Linq to SQL para trazer os dados da database.

Comment: Coloque o código que você usa para popular a datagrid.

Comment: Já tentou este comando?  TableAdapter.Fill(DataSet.Tabela);